# How does $1-\rho^2$ in the bivariate case, turn into $\det(\boldsymbol\Sigma)$ in the multivariate?

Tags: statistics, determinant, information-theory, covariance, correlation

**Bivariate mutual information** for two Gaussian variables $X$ and $Y$ is well-known:

$$I(X;Y) = -\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-\rho^2)$$
where $\rho$ is the bivariate correlation coefficient.

**Multivariate mutual information**, according to Doquire and Verleysen (2012), is therefore

$$I(X_1; X_2;\dots ; X_n) = -\frac{1}{2}\ln (\det(\boldsymbol\Sigma)) $$
where $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix, and $\det$ is the determinant.

What is the connection between correlation and the determinant of the covariance matrix here? How does $1-\rho^2$ in the bivariate case, turn into $\det(\boldsymbol\Sigma)$? Please show steps of the derivation.

Comment: At least for the second case, I think you are starting with standard Gaussians (mean $0$, variance $1$) so $\Sigma$ is also a correlation matrix, and it is obvious that the first case is essentially the second when $n=2$

Comment: could you show the steps line-by-line. how is it for the non-standard Normal as well as standard Normal

Comment: You should define $I(X_1; X_2; ... X_n)$ as there is another interpretation for your question as a mutual information between two multivariate Gaussian vectors $I(X_1,...X_n;Y_1,...,Y_n)$; presumably you mean $I(X_1;X_2; ... X_n)=h(X_1)+...+h(X_n) - h(X_1,...,X_n)$

Comment: No, i am only using the definition for gaussian information, given in the cited source. But am aware of the many different alternatives. They are not the question at hand

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me, that the cited formula is wrong. Also, the authors of the paper refer to another paper, in which I didn't find the mentioned formula at all. If we define the mutual information as customary as the KL divergence between the joint distribution and the product distribution of the respective marginals then in the Gaussian case one gets
\begin{equation}
I(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{\det(\Sigma_{0})}{\det(\Sigma_{1})},
\end{equation}
with $\Sigma_{0}$ being the covariance matrix of the multivariate Gaussian in question and $\Sigma_{1}$ the covariance matrix of the marginal product measure. Thus, $\Sigma_{1}$ is just the diagonal matrix with the same diagonal entries as $\Sigma_{0}$. And indeed in the two-dimensional setting, we recover your first formula since
\begin{equation}
\det(\Sigma_{0})=\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}-\sigma_{12}^{2}\quad\text{ and }\quad \det(\Sigma_{1})=\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}.
\end{equation}
The quotient thus reads
\begin{equation}
1-\frac{\sigma_{12}^{2}}{\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}}
\end{equation}
which is $1-\rho^{2}$.

Comment: I could not find the formula in their cited source (Verleysen) either

Comment: Maybe you are able to solve this related question as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914826/what-is-the-closed-form-analytical-solution-for-multivariate-gaussian-mutual-inf

Comment: That is answered above already.

Comment: can you give a source demonstrating more details on the usage and meaning of dividing the determinant of the sample covariance matrix by the determinant of its diagonal? It would help me understand how this compares to the matrix $K$ from the otherp ost

Comment: @Tobsn for the multivariate formula, do you have a reference or link to said derivation?