# Derivation of mutual information's closed-form analytical solution

Tags: statistics, logarithms, information-theory, entropy, gaussian

$$I(X;Y) = -\frac{1}{2} \ln(1-\rho^2)$$ is the **mutual information** between two Gaussian random variables. What source derived this formula? Could we have the full derivation here as an answer.

### First Attempt

Given $f(x)$ is the Gaussian p.d.f. of variable $X$ and $f(y)$ is the Gaussian p.d.f. of variable $Y$, and
\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=\frac{1}{\left( (2\pi)^{n}\det{(\boldsymbol
\Sigma)}\right)^\frac{1}{2}  }\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\top\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})%
\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma_X \sigma_Y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} 
\exp \left\{ -\frac{1}{2\left(1-\rho^2\right)} \left[ \left(\frac{x-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right)^2
+ \left(\frac{y-\mu_{Y}}{\sigma_{Y}}\right)^2 -2\rho \left(\frac{x-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}\right) \left(\frac{y-\mu_{X}}{\sigma_{Y}}\right) \right] \right\}
\end{align}
is the joint distribution where $\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{\mu}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ are the data observations, means and covariance matrix of the joint distribution,

\begin{align}
I(X;Y) &= \int \int f(x,y) \ln \frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)f(y)} dx dy\\
&= \int \int f(x,y) \ln \frac{f(x,y)}{\left(2\pi \sigma_X^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-(x-\mu_X)^2 / 2\sigma_X^2} \cdot \left(2\pi \sigma_Y^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-(y-\mu_Y)^2 / 2\sigma_Y^2}} dx dy\\
&= ?
\end{align}

Comment: I removed my downvote, @develarist.  Thanks for informing me.

Comment: The book Elements of Information Theory by Cover (page 252, Example 8.5.1) has a short proof of the above. Link: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~cgong821/Wiley.Interscience.Elements.of.Information.Theory.Jul.2006.eBook-DDU.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X, Y) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, K),$ where
$$
K=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma^{2} & \rho \sigma^{2} \\
\rho \sigma^{2} & \sigma^{2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Then $$h(X)=h(Y)=\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi e) \sigma^{2}$$ and $$h(X, Y)=\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi e)^{2}|K|=
\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi e)^{2} \sigma^{4}\left(1-\rho^{2}\right),$$ and therefore
$$
I(X ; Y)=h(X)+h(Y)-h(X, Y)=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1-\rho^{2}\right)
$$
If $\rho=0, X$ and $Y$ are independent and the mutual information is 0 . If $\rho=\pm 1, X$ and $Y$ are perfectly correlated and the mutual information is infinite.

Comment: Why should $K$ be of that particular form?

Comment: I asked the exact same question here: "why are the covariance terms in $K$ equal to $ρσ^2$ instead of $ρσ_Xσ_Y$? Is this solution assuming $σ_X=σ_Y$ and why would anyone assume that?"  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914831/joint-entropy-closed-form-analytical-solution

Comment: You don't need that assumption in order to derive the formula in question. As I said aleady, basically my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907068/how-does-1-rho2-in-the-bivariate-case-turn-into-det-boldsymbol-sigma-i/3908332#3908332 contains the full and general argument.

Comment: I'm not arguing one approach is better than the other, but the answer shown here comes from the Cover and Thomas textbook. That's why I want to understand why they assumed what they assumed

Comment: They are not different at all. It's just a rewriting of the same thing. Yet, the matirx $K$ above is a special situation and not the general situation, which would rather be $\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{X}^{2} & \rho\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}\\
\rho\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y} & \sigma_{Y}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$ You will end up with the same conclusion using this matrix.

Comment: *why* did they choose to show the special situation over the general one? Was it because they were assuming  the standard Normal case only, where variances are all equal to 1? that's the only explanation I could think of

Comment: I guess just for the sake of simplicity and space saving. Apart, it's not a big jump from this special to the general case.